# How can a DCR file create a text file

Tags: adobe-director

I have just creating a game that is played on the web (with shockwave player DCR)

I wanted to make HIGHSCORE.txt lingo, for the game.

As for projector.exe: I can use getpref and setpref lingo command, no problem.

But for the game DCR on the web, the getpref and setpref seemed to be not working,
There's no highscore.txt created within the web folder. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

getpref() and setpref() do generally work well in Shockwave, I'm don't know what folder you are looking for the text file in but according to the Adobe docs here is where the text file is saved:

> Windows Shockwave
>       ..\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Adobe\Shockwave Player \Prefs\
>   MAC Shockwave
>       ~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Shockwave Player/Prefs

setpref() can fail if the user is running in an environment with especially restrictive security settings but that is rare.  Full docs here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Director/11.5/UsingScripting/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811d64c1a1b3-7ecf.html